# ruby on rails 4 mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have:

- a model User for common data such as email, password, first_name, last_name
- a model Student for specific data such as faculty_id, etc..

What i want is to have a possibility to modify student's profile, e.g change its faculty and credentials. I found out that accepts_nested_attributes_for should help me with that. So that is what i have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_one :student
 has_one :header
 has_one :admin
 has_many :progresses, :through => :student

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :student

end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  has_one :specialization, through: :group
  has_many :progresses
  scope :activated, lambda {(where("users.activated = 'off'"))}
  self.per_page = 1

end

class Admin::StudentsController < AdminController

 before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @students = Student.joins(:user).joins(:group).paginate(:page => params[:page]).all
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  private
   def set_user
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.build_user
   end
end
```

Form partial

```
= form_for([:admin,@student]) do |f|
 - if @student.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
   h2
    = pluralize(@student.errors.count, "error")
    | prohibited this group from being saved:
   ul
    - @student.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      li= msg
  .field
   = f.fields_for :user do |builder|
   = builder.label :first_name
  br/
   = builder.text_field :first_name
  .field
  = f.label :faculty_id
  br/
  = f.text_field :faculty_id
.actions
= f.submit
```

I looked into inspect element in a browser and input for user object is

```
<input id="student_user_first_name" name="student[user][first_name]" type="text">
```

which seems correct. But the field is empty. Please tell me where i went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: what actions should be made for that?

Comment: submit submitting the form

Comment: for now i just want first_name from user model to be displayed in the student edit form, i don't have a logic for an update yet.

Comment: Ok, but little confusion there if you want to display user fields in student form then you have to remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for :student` from user model and add following to student model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user`

Comment: did that, nothing changed:(

Comment: https://github.com/amit4m2008/survay check out this link where i have created sample app with nested attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 uses Strong Parameters, so you need to whitelist your params in the controller. Here is a good explanation which considers the use of accepts_nested_attribute_for. http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html